# How do I expand a custom collection view cell that has a table view on it?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to automatically make a collectionView cell expand vertically to show a tableView that is on the cell.

The tableView is being correctly populated, and I am calling reload on the collection view cell after setting `cell.tableView.isHidden = false`

Swift 4.2, Xcode 10.3

***Edit: To clarify my question, I am trying to toggle expand/collapse the cell  (with auto resize) when I show/hide the tableView on the cell.***

collectionView flowLayout var:

```
// FlowLayout of the collectionView 
var flowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        return self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
}
```

collectionView viewDidLoad():

```
self.flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
```

collectionView cell:

```
override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
        setNeedsLayout()
        layoutIfNeeded()

        let size = contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(layoutAttributes.size)
        var frame = layoutAttributes.frame

        frame.size.height = ceil(size.height)
        layoutAttributes.frame = frame

        let autoLayoutAttributes = super.preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(layoutAttributes)

        // Specify you want _full width_
        let targetSize = CGSize(width: layoutAttributes.frame.width, height: 0)

        // Calculate the size (height) using Auto Layout
        let autoLayoutSize = contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(targetSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority.required, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority.defaultLow)
        let autoLayoutFrame = CGRect(origin: autoLayoutAttributes.frame.origin, size: autoLayoutSize)

        // Assign the new size to the layout attributes
        autoLayoutAttributes.frame = autoLayoutFrame
        return autoLayoutAttributes
}
```

collectionView cell when "show table view" button is tapped:

```
cell.tableView.isHidden = false
collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any question here, you are able to populate the UICollectionViewCell correctly, isn't that what you want?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have added a bit of clarity in my original post: 

To clarify my question, I am trying to toggle expand/collapse the cell (with auto resize) when I show/hide the tableView on the cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {


let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! yourCell

if cell.tableView.isHidden { 

return CGize(width: cellWidth, height:0)

  } 

    return  CGSize(width: tableViewWidth, height: TotalTableViewCellsHeight)     



}
```

Or

```
 @IBAction func showTableView(_ sender: Any) {

 flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: newCellWidth, height: newCellHeight)

   }
```